# Extra parentheses cause simple media query to fail

Tags: css, media-queries, boolean-logic

I just came across a weird thing and was wondering if this is expected behaviour or indeed some sort of bug.

My intention is to write the following code but I narrowed down the issue (see below).

```
@media only screen
 and (
   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2),   /* or */
   (min-resolution: 120dpi)
 ) { ... }
```

This code works:

```
@media only screen
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2) { ... }
```

adding extra outside parentheses (round brackets), this fails:

```
@media only screen
 and ( (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2) ) { ... }
```

The target platform is latest Chrome on Android 5.1, but I'm open to hear comments on other platforms too.

Comment: did you try `@media only screen and  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2),   only screen and  (min-resolution: 120dpi) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what behavior you need to approach. Whether you need `and` or `or` for those rules

If you want to apply both of rules for media query, you need to use `and` logical operator

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2)
                   and (min-resolution: 120dpi) 
{ ... }
```

If you want to apply any one of the rules for media query, you need to use *comma* :

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.2), 
       only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi)
{ ... }
```